# Failed Building Red5 App in Ubuntu

Tags: java, build, permissions, red5

I want to build my red5 app using eclipse with red5plugin in ubuntu. But when I publish my app it shows error like this :

```
Buildfile: /home/riset/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jst.server.generic.core/sjsas.xml
-checkWebDeploy:
deploy.j2ee.web:
[chmod] chmod: changing permissions of `/usr/local/red5/red5.sh': Operation not permitted
[chmod] Result: 1
[jar] Building jar: /home/riset/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/reg_server.jar
[copy] Copying 1 file to /usr/local/red5/webapps/reg_server/WEB-INF/lib

BUILD FAILED
/home/riset/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jst.server.generic.core/sjsas.xml:49: Failed to copy /home/riset/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/reg_server.jar to /usr/local/red5/webapps/reg_server/WEB-INF/lib/reg_server.jar due to failed to create the parent directory for /usr/local/red5/webapps/reg_server/WEB-INF/lib/reg_server.jar

Total time: 964 milliseconds
```

I try to change folder permission using : `chmod -R 755 red5`, but it's nothing to do with it.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [chmod] chmod: changing permissions of `/usr/local/red5/red5.sh': Operation not permitted

It seems you do not have permission to use `/usr/local/red5/red5.sh' bash, try [sudo] when open your eclipse.